# Polyphase decimation matlab

Tags: matlab, decimation

I am new to DSP, and currently trying to implement a simple polyphase decimation program in matlab.

M is decimation factor, x is input (for now it is a square wave 8096 samples), y_polyDec is result from polyphase, output is result from regular filter then decimation.

code :

```
FilterBank_LPF = fir1(127, 1/M);
y_polyDec = zeros(8096/M, 1);

for i = 1:M

    p(:, i) = FilterBank_LPF(i:M:end);
    x(:, i) = input(M-i+1:M:end);
    y_polyDec = filter(p(:, i), 1, x(:, i))+ y_polyDec;

end

out_LPF = filter(FilterBank_LPF, 1, input);
output = downsample(out_LPF, M);

%===========================================
```

If I compare "output" and "y_polyDec" (either comparing the decimated sample values or frequency spectrum using fvtool) I notice there are differences in the values. I was wondering if my code is wrong, or am I still missing something.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the input signals to your polyphase filters. They should be delayed and subsampled versions of the input signal, like in the following code fragment:

```
M=8;    % downsampling factor
L=256;  % length of input signal, integer multiple of M
x=randn(L,1);  % input signal
h = fir1(127, 1/M);
yp = zeros(L/M, 1);

for i = 1:M,
    xtmp = [zeros(i-1,1); x];  % delayed input signal
    tmp = filter( h(i:M:end), 1, xtmp(1:M:L) );  % polyphase filtering
    yp = yp + tmp;  % accumulate outputs of polyphase filters
end

% compare with standard filtering
y = filter ( h, 1, x);
yM = downsample( y, M );

n=1:L/M;
plot(n,(yM-yp)/max(yM))
```

Comment: You would wanted to convert this to a polyphase channelizer, where would you add the IDFT?